# Using jekyll with gitlab pages, it says when it's deploying the website with gitlab CI that theme could not be found, and I already installed it

Tags: ruby, gitlab, jekyll, gitlab-ci, jekyll-theme

### My objetive

To have a repository with the jekyll site configuration files (but not the _site), and each time I push to the repository, a gitlab pipeline runs. With that pipeline, the site is build with Jekyll (I'm using this theme https://github.com/mmistakes/jekyll-theme-basically-basic)

### A quick view on the essential files which I'm troubling with

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0.0"
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.

#######
#THEMES
#######

# MANUALLY COMMENTED
#gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
# New content by me
#gem "jekyll-theme-basically-basic"
#gem 'jekyll-theme-basically-basic', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.4'

########################



# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
install_if -> { RUBY_PLATFORM =~ %r!mingw|mswin|java! } do
  # gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  # gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
# gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :install_if => Gem.win_platform?
```

Maybe you are wondering why so many comments there. That's because I was having problems with the deployment in gitlab, and I found out that If I installed them in the .gitlab-ci.yml, I wouldn't encounter those problems.

_config.yml

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely edit after that. If you find
# yourself editing this file very often, consider using Jekyll's data files
# feature for the data you need to update frequently.
#
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'bundle exec jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.
#
# If you need help with YAML syntax, here are some quick references for you: 
# https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/markdown-yaml-cheat-sheet/#yaml
# https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
#
# Site settings
# These are used to personalize your new site. If you look in the HTML files,
# you will see them accessed via {{ site.title }}, {{ site.email }}, and so on.
# You can create any custom variable you would like, and they will be accessible
# in the templates via {{ site.myvariable }}.

lang: es-ES
title: La casa de los titanes
email: adristudy@gmail.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
author:
  name: Adrián Jaramillo
twitter_username: sample
github_username: sample

# Build settings
theme: jekyll-theme-basically-basic
#theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default.
# Any item listed under the `exclude:` key here will be automatically added to
# the internal "default list".
#
# Excluded items can be processed by explicitly listing the directories or
# their entries' file path in the `include:` list.
#
# exclude:
#   - .sass-cache/
#   - .jekyll-cache/
#   - gemfiles/
#   - Gemfile
#   - Gemfile.lock
#   - node_modules/
#   - vendor/bundle/
#   - vendor/cache/
#   - vendor/gems/
#   - vendor/ruby/

# New content by me 
# theme: jekyll-theme-basically-basic
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.5

pages:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  #- gem install minima
  - gem install jekyll-theme-basically-basic -v 1.4.1
  - gem install tzinfo -v 1.2.2
  - gem install tzinfo-data
  - bundle install
  - jekyll build --trace -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

### Furthermore, you have here the public repository

https://gitlab.com/unveiled_adri/jekyll_project

### And of course, the whole process of deployment on the docker vm of gitlab, which shows the error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:092689b795107d1b2eadb82494acf4764191baa0aa5bf4673b8ee2a50f70ba97 for ruby:2.5 ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-14628881-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1571178048-5f8825dc...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/unveiled_adri/jekyll_project/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/unveiled_adri/jekyll_project
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/89060084 -> refs/pipelines/89060084
 * [new branch]      master                  -> origin/master
Checking out 745d8811 as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ gem install jekyll
Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.1
Successfully installed addressable-2.7.0
Successfully installed colorator-1.1.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed http_parser.rb-0.6.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.2.7
Successfully installed em-websocket-0.5.1
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.5

HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
But that may break your application.

Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.

For more info see:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0

Successfully installed i18n-1.7.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.11.1
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed sassc-2.2.1
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-2.0.1
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.3
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.10.0
Successfully installed listen-3.2.0
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-2.2.1
Successfully installed kramdown-2.1.0
Successfully installed kramdown-parser-gfm-1.1.0
Successfully installed liquid-4.0.3
Successfully installed mercenary-0.3.6
Successfully installed forwardable-extended-2.6.0
Successfully installed pathutil-0.16.2
Successfully installed rouge-3.12.0
Successfully installed safe_yaml-1.0.5
Successfully installed unicode-display_width-1.6.0
Successfully installed terminal-table-1.8.0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jekyll 4.0 comes with some major changes, notably:

  * Our `link` tag now comes with the `relative_url` filter incorporated into it.
    You should no longer prepend `{{ site.baseurl }}` to `{% link foo.md %}`
    For further details: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6727

  * Our `post_url` tag now comes with the `relative_url` filter incorporated into it.
    You shouldn't prepend `{{ site.baseurl }}` to `{% post_url 2019-03-27-hello %}`
    For further details: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/7589

  * Support for deprecated configuration options has been removed. We will no longer
    output a warning and gracefully assign their values to the newer counterparts
    internally.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Successfully installed jekyll-4.0.0
26 gems installed
$ gem install jekyll-theme-basically-basic -v 1.4.1
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
Successfully installed sass-listen-4.0.0

Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.

* If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
  primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

* If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
  sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

* For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
  https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841

Successfully installed sass-3.7.4
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2
Successfully installed kramdown-1.17.0
Successfully installed jekyll-3.8.6
Successfully installed jekyll-sitemap-1.3.1
Successfully installed jekyll-seo-tag-2.6.1
Successfully installed jekyll-paginate-1.1.0
Successfully installed jekyll-feed-0.12.1
Successfully installed jekyll-theme-basically-basic-1.4.1
11 gems installed
$ gem install tzinfo -v 1.2.2
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
2 gems installed
$ gem install tzinfo-data
Successfully installed tzinfo-data-1.2019.3
1 gem installed
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 4.0.1
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.1
Using ffi 1.11.1
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using i18n 1.7.0
Using sassc 2.2.1
Using jekyll-sass-converter 2.0.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using listen 3.2.0
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Using kramdown 2.1.0
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using rouge 3.12.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using unicode-display_width 1.6.0
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using jekyll 4.0.0
Using jekyll-feed 0.12.1
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 28 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `/usr/local/bundle`
$ jekyll build --trace -d public/
Configuration file: /builds/unveiled_adri/jekyll_project/_config.yml
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:76:in `rescue in gemspec': The jekyll-theme-basically-basic theme could not be found. (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:73:in `gemspec'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:18:in `root'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:487:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:487:in `configure_theme'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:58:in `config='
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

### Conclusion

I have tried everything but at this almost last point of the deployment I'm completely lost. I could solve the installation problems but now I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`, uncomment `#gem "jekyll-theme-basically-basic"` to read `gem "jekyll-theme-basically-basic"`.

For some reasons, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, all the `gem install ...` are useless, and it's the `bundle install` that does the required job.

Comment: The reason why I commented all the gem lines in the Gemfile is because the vm in gitlab was saying that it couldn't find the gems in the gem source. This was so strange for me because in my Gemfile, the gem source is the default one, and I also checked that the gems exist in that source. In addition, this was all working on my local vm. So, I reached the solution that I needed to install the gems in the .gitlab-ci.yml, but then I came across with this error. What do you think then I should do?

Comment: anyways I'll try what you said again, maybe magic happens @David Jacquel

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the solution because it actually solved the question. The problem now is that the webpage is deployed in a weird way. I mean, the css is broken and some links doesn't work. You can check the gitlab page of the repository if you want to see and maybe you know what happened. Anyways, I'll open here another post to ask about that

Comment: @AdriánJaramillo you need to set `url` properly for the CSS url to be accssible.